# 3D projection of depth + color

Tags: c++, image-processing, kinect, projection

I have a color image along with its depth map which both are captured by Kinect. I want to project it to another location (to see how it looks like in another viewpoint). Since I don't have the intrinsic parameters (camera param.) of the Kinect; How can I implement it?

P.S: I'm writing my codes in C++.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this, Have you considered using ROS (Robot operating system), it has a built in driver for the kinect and a great visualiser which you can zoom around with and view any angle you like.

Comment: Ben- I'm trying to compare the original depth map of Kinect with the one that I have post-processed. One good way is to compare the results of view synthesis. I want to know how to get the synthesized image while I don't have any camera parameters.

Comment: I know not C++, but interesting: http://www.renauddumont.be/en/2012/kinect-sdk-1-0-4-kinect-en-profondeur-avec-le-depthstream

Answer (score 1):

With the depth frame and the color frame you should have enough data to achieve something similar to what you want to do.

In the color frame, you have the color of each pixels.
In the depth frame, you have the distance of each pixels.

(Keep in mind that there is a small gap between the data in the depth frame and the color frame due to the position of each sensor. Have a look at the mapping helper methods : [MapDepthFrameToColorFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor.mapdepthframetocolorframe))

If you take all the data in both the depth and the color frame, at the same time, you could draw each pixel as a point in a 3-dimensional world. Let's say you have a resolution of 640x480. You'll have a scene drawn in a rectangle of 640 (x = width), 480 (y = height), ~3000 (z = depth). Then you can change the point of view !

The only problem is that you won't have the right scale for the Z axis. If you want a better result, you should also use the SkeletonFrame. Thanks to that you'll have the actual X, Y, and Z values (in meters). Once again you can use the helper method ([MapDepthToSkeletonPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973090)) to get the corresponding skeleton point for each depth point !

If you look at [this post](http://www.renauddumont.be/en/2012/kinect-sdk-1-0-4-kinect-en-profondeur-avec-le-depthstream), you'll find  a video that shows the result, some piece of code in C#, and a project sample that you can reuse.

Comment: Thank you Renaud, Regarding the gap between depth and color; I already rectified the color image to be matched with depth map. I will go through the post you sent; I looks interesting.